# HOw can send data in gmail like table format its possible becaus the mail can't support brake line aur new line its send me data only on line .C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, email

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;
using System.Net.Mail;


namespace Sonex.WebFrom
{
    public partial class Customr_Confrm : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        SqlConnection con;
        myDb db = new myDb();
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Application["TotalPrice"] == null)
            {
                Response.Redirect("Coustomer_Home_page.aspx");
            }
            else
            TextBoxtotalprice.Text = Application["TotalPrice"].ToString();
            txtquatnity.Text = Application["Quanity"].ToString();
        }
//send data to gmail
        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           Application.Clear();
            con = db.createConnection("Sonex");
            con = db.connectionOpen(con);
//the data i acces the database and send in mail
            if (db.crudOperation("insert into Customer_purchase (Date,Name,City,Postal_Code,PhoneNumber,Address,Email) Values('" + TextBoxDate.Text.Trim() + "', '" + TextBoxfname.Text.Trim() + "','" + TextBoxcity.Text.Trim() + "','" + TextBoxPostal.Text.Trim() + "','" + TextBoxPhonenum.Text.Trim() + "','" + TextBoxAddres.Text.Trim() + "','" + TextBoxemai.Text.Trim() + "')", con) > 0)
            {
                MailMessage Msg = new MailMessage();
                Msg.From = new MailAddress("abc@gmail.com");
                Msg.To.Add("xyz@gmail.com");
                Msg.Subject = "hELLO";
//i want to send data in gmail in one table and show mail in table form

                Msg.Body = "     Date= \n  \n" + TextBoxDate.Text + Environment.NewLine + "     NAME=   \n" + TextBoxfname.Text + TextBoxDate.Text + Environment.NewLine + "     City=   \n" + TextBoxcity.Text + TextBoxDate.Text + Environment.NewLine + "     Postal=   \n" + TextBoxPostal.Text + TextBoxDate.Text + Environment.NewLine + "     PhoneNumber=   \n" + TextBoxPhonenum.Text + TextBoxDate.Text + Environment.NewLine + "     Addres=   \n" + TextBoxAddres.Text + TextBoxDate.Text + Environment.NewLine + "     Email=   \n" + TextBoxemai.Text + TextBoxDate.Text + Environment.NewLine + "     TOtoal Quantity=   \n" + txtquatnity.Text + TextBoxDate.Text + Environment.NewLine + "     TotalPrice=   \n" + TextBoxtotalprice.Text;
                Msg.IsBodyHtml = true;

                SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
                smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
                System.Net.NetworkCredential Networkcred = new System.Net.NetworkCredential();
                Networkcred.UserName = "mno75@gmail.com";
                Networkcred.Password = "**********";
                smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
                smtp.Credentials = Networkcred;
                smtp.Port = 587;
                smtp.EnableSsl = true;
                smtp.Send(Msg);
                Label1.Text = "Email has been Send........";
                Label2.Text = "Data Successfully Inserted";
            }
            else
                Label1.Text = "try agin";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you mean to assign HTML text to Msg.Body? You can then use the <br /> tag to denote a line break

Comment: Thank You Biscuits